# Express: Safest way to parse parse objects passed to ejs file:

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I am using express and suppose I want to pass the following to my ejs:

`evilUser = { name: "evil", passwordHash: "rememberToNotSendSecrets", evenBetter: "store secrets separately", profileText: "I like to own noob webmasters</script><script>window.alert(1337);</script>" }`

Now if I `render` it on `index.ejs`, it would trigger the window alert, making it unsafe. Is there a way to pass it safely such that it all html/js attacks are removed from the object?

Comment: why don't you use `JSON.stringify(evilUser)`?

Answer (score 0):

Before passing it to ejs you could sanitize the object and go through each key-value pairs in the object and search for the script tags. Then slice out the script tags and the contents within.